# Problem with the fall time of op-amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, high-speed, rise-time

I am designing a "simple" current source using an op-amplifier. My question is why is my fall time looking like that:

[image]

What do I need to reduce the fall time? Here is the schematic:

[image]

Comment: A WIDEBAND OPERATION The ADA4817-1/ADA4817-2 provides excellent performance as a high speed buffer. Figure 52 shows the circuit used for wideband characterization for high gains. Feedback resistances of 100 Ω to 400 Ω are recommended because they minimize the peaking and they do not degrade the performance of the output stage. As suggested in figure 66 of datasheet, try lower feedback resistors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The op-amp you have chosen cannot properly turn off the MOSFET: -

[image]

The diagram above tells you that the output doesn't swing down to 0 volts (the negative rail of your op-amp) but to about 1 volt to 1.2 volts above 0 volts. This means your MOSFET cannot be turned off that easily. Try adding a small negative rail to your op-amp -Vs supply pin.

You might also be able to improve it a little by connecting the op-amp output to the MOSFET gate via a potential divider to remove a further half volt of gate drive.